# L-0 matrix norm in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I am working on tensorflow 1.01.
I am trying to modify an example found at: 
https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/tree/master/03_Linear_Regression/07_Implementing_Elasticnet_Regression

My model is a simple linear model

```
x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

# Create variables for linear regression
A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[3,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1,1]))

# Declare model operations
model_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_data, A), b)
```

Specifically, I would like to add another L0 penalty term to the model loss, same way as done with L2 norm:

```
l2_a_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(A))
elastic_param2 = tf.constant(1.)
e2_term = tf.multiply(elastic_param2, l2_a_loss)
```

However, I can not compute a loss using L0 norm

```
elastic_param0= tf.constant(1.)
l0_a_loss= tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(A,ord=0))
e0_term= tf.multiply(elastic_param0, l0_a_loss)
```

plugging in the additional term in the model loss

```
loss = tf.expand_dims(tf.add(tf.add(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_target -     model_output)), e0_term), e2_term), 0)
```

returns

```
ValueError: 'ord' must be a supported vector norm, got 0.
```

I was hoping that changing the axis argument value would fix it while also with

```
l0_a_loss= tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(A,ord=0,axis=(0,1)))
```

I still get

```
ValueError: 'ord' must be a supported matrix norm in ['euclidean', 'fro', 1, inf], got 0
```

How to minimize the L-0 norm of A in this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensorflow documentation is wrong (even in current 1.3 version).

As you can see from [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b04d3f2e5147baa99d994cc94029cb5136916604):

> Fix description of tf.norm as it doesn't actually accept `ord=0`.

This means that you have to implement the L0 norm by yourself, you can't use `tf.norm`

Comment: for norm=+inf I have successfully used l_inf_a_loss= tf.reduce_max(A)  I have been trying to the same with l0_a_loss=tf.count_nonzero(A) but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarly solved this by:

```
l0_a_loss=tf.cast( tf.count_nonzero(A), tf.float32)
```

Looking forward to official documentation/code update in tensorflow

Comment: But this is not differentiable, is it?

Comment: is L1 differentiable?L1 can be used afaik

Comment: L1 is differentiable and can induce sparsity as well.